# Trying to Understand Proof of Clairaut's Theorem in Stewart textbook

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus, proof-explanation, partial-derivative

I am learning multivariable calculus. I'm having difficulty following the proof of Clairaut's Theorem in Section 14.3, the section on partial derivates of the 8th edition of Stewart's text. The proof included in the following screenshot is in Appendix F of the book.

Could someone please help me understand the step highlighted in yellow below? I am getting lost in the algebra. I attempted to draw some pictures to understand what is happening geometrically in 3D, but this was not too fruitful. Explanations that help improve my intuitive understanding of the expression for $\Delta$ (h) which begins the proof will be much appreciated in addition to working out the algebraic manipulations.

Edit: Can someone help me understand the second application of the mean value theorem? I do not understand the mean value theorem applied to multivariable functions.
Thank you to those who have helped me already.

[image: The proof of Clairaut's Theorem]

Comment: The first displayed equation of the proof shows an expression for $\Delta(h)$ which is the difference of two expressions each in square brackets.

The first bracketed expression is simply $g(a+h)$, and the second bracketed expression is just $g(a)$. Remember, $g(\square) = f(\square, b+h) - f(\square,b)$. The first bracketed expression puts $a+h$ in for $\square$, and the second puts $a$ in for $\square$.

Is that what's giving you trouble?

Comment: Thanks very much, I didn't recognize that connection between the bracketed expressions and g(a+h) and g(h). So I was getting confused working out algebra of subtractions without seeing it clearly. Thanks a ton for the help

Answer (score 0):

Just notice that, by the definition of $g$,
$$
g(a+h)=f(a+h,b+h)-f(a+h,b)
$$
Whereas
$$
g(a)=f(a,b+h)-f(a,b)
$$
Therefore
$$
g(a+h)-g(a)= f(a+h,b+h)-f(a+h,b)-f(a,b+h)+f(a,b)=
$$
$$
=[f(a+h,b+h)-f(a+h,b)]-[f(a,b+h)-f(a,b)].
$$

Comment: Thank you so much for the timely help